# Canon SDK (EdsGetPropertyDesc)

Tags: sdk, edsdk

I was playing with the canon 2.10 SDK (eos)
and I'm having trouble understanding the `EdsGetPropertyDesc` `PropDesc` array of data. 
The value within the array doesn't look like my camera options.

For example the `Av` values includes 40,43,45,48,51,53,... while my camera has 4, 4.5, 5, 5.6,...

Do I have to convert the value somehow?

Answer (score 1):

here the `Av` values in Hex. you can map it with your camara settings

```
value      Aperture Value
---------------------------
Ox40       11  
Ox43       13 (1/3)  
0x44       13    
0x45       14
0x48       16     
0x50       22
0x53       25
```

you will find the full Aperture table here `kEdsPropID_Av` [EDSDK API](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3amdhN7DAlfr0J%3awww.assembla.com/spaces/CanonEOSApp/documents/aP8H0mUaqr3OlDeJe5afGb/download/aP8H0mUaqr3OlDeJe5afGb+edsdk+api+pdf&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgehWFrlZw2EWtHs7HMJzyrjv9YJGAcFQpMgMIp4NQu_9oL4kkMfZ-G7NNFRnCdAxvnCEyR9cTWVaU4vm_p0yoZTQGGUPnpk6igvujGwX-hlM02IHmCbEhAKCfRAT-n1RwUgska&sig=AHIEtbQfVzTRUlqwWmGmLvJLgllwQPMo8Q)